# Copy sheet with combo boxes

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, copy-paste

I have a worksheet that is copied and pasted into a new worksheet when the user clicks on a button. I've managed to copy everything in the worksheet (shapes, buttons, etc.) except for the combo boxes that contain dropdown lists using named ranges (which are created with the following code: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal11.html).

I tried to record a macro for this and got the following (simplified)

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ExampleCombo")).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

With this I understood that the combo box is regarded as a shape. In order to copy all combo boxes and put them in the right position in the new sheet I therefore tried the following:

```
 Sub CopyCombos ()

 Dim ws_new As Worksheet
 Dim ws_old As Worksheet
 Dim Special_Shape As Shape
 Dim Special_Shape_COPY As Shape
 Dim Position_Left As Single
 Dim Position_Top As Single
 Dim Position_Width As Single
 Dim Position_Height As Single

 Set ws_old = ActiveSheet
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
 Set ws_new = ActiveSheet

 For Each Special_Shape In ws_old.Shapes
     'Copy position
         Position_Left = Special_Shape.Left
         Position_Top = Special_Shape.Top
         Position_Width = Special_Shape.Width
         Position_Height = Special_Shape.Height
     'Copy
         Special_Shape.Copy
     'Paste
         ws_new.Paste   '<=== Here's the problem! But why?
     'Rename
         Set Special_Shape_COPY = Selection
     'Put in right place
         Special_Shape_COPY.Left = Position_Left
         Special_Shape_COPY.Top = Position_Top
         Special_Shape_COPY.Width = Position_Width
         Special_Shape_COPY.Height = Position_Height
 Next Special_Shape

 End Sub
```

I get an error message saying "Can't enter break mode at this time" directly after pasting the combo box in the new worksheet. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than:

```
 Set ws_old = ActiveSheet
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
 Set ws_new = ActiveSheet
```

and doing copies, use:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

This will produce a complete copy:

1. rows
2. cells
3. Objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of *Gary's Student* to copy the worksheet worked just fine when copying it within the same workbook:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

However this causes a problem when copying the sheet to another (new) workbook as the format differs in colors. To solve this I used the following code before adding a new workbook:

```
Workbooks.Add Template:="Workbook"
```